# How to mock a public readonly field

Tags: mocking, moq

Using Moq how can i mock the following class so i it return dummy values in my unit tests:

```
public abstract class DataService
{
    public readonly string DataDirectory; //I need to mock the return value

    protected DataService()
    {
        DataDirectory = "c:\temp";
    }
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT**

Adding more meat to the class so the problem can be understood:

```
public abstract class DataService
{
    public readonly DirectoryInfo DataDirectory;

    protected GitService()
    {
        DataDirectory = new DirectoryInfo("c:\temp");
    }

    public virtual object GetRepositoryByName(string name)
    {
         //Locate the repo, build it and return it
         string path = Path.Combine(DataDirectory.FullName, name);
         return new BuildRepository(path);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you change your code instead? Make it a property instead of a publicly accessible field. Other than constants (or effective constants, public static readonly immutable values) you should generally make fields private anyway.

You could also change your class to allow the value to be injected into it, rather than it having to come up with it itself. It depends what you're really trying to do.

Comment: The code can change since its still experimental.  As you can see its an abstract class which we are trying to provide some default behavior.  Once set we don't want the DataDirectory to change at all.  What design do you recommend which can also fit nicely with mocking?

Comment: @Fixer: You can make it a read-only property - but why do you particularly need to *mock* this? This seems like a good candidate for another kind of test double - potentially a fake - or possibly a mock which passes the desired data directory into the constructor for the abstract class. It's hard to give more concrete advice without knowing what you're trying to test.

Comment: Thanks Jon - I've added a more complete example - The original example may have thrown you off a little.  Anyway my mock code is failing because when i tried to mock the abstract class and call the method under test it threw an exception (since DirectoryInfo is null).

Comment: @Fixer: So what are you trying to test - DataService or something that depends on it?

Comment: Yes trying to test the DataService

Comment: @Fixer: In that case I wouldn't be mocking *that*. You normally mock dependencies, not the class under test.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in the same issue, and as far as I understand the way to do that it's via the Setup and Returns methods.

```
var mock = Mock<DataService>();
mock.Setup(m => m.DataDirectory).Returns(new DirectoryInfo("c:\temp");
```

The problem it's that you need to operate with virtual methods so cannot be readonly

I finally did an interface and went away of readonly for the classes that I do want to mock

```
var mock = Mock<IDataService>();
mock.Setup(m.DataDirectory).Returns(new DirectoryInfo("c:\temp");
```

Edit: my original answer was partially wrong.